# Excel VBA Paste Special

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to eliminate a manual process that a user is doing. They have a VBA Button that when clicked will parse the text on the sheet to another sheet.

```
The procedure goes:
1. Copy Contents from HTML Site
2. Paste contents from clipboard as "PASTE SPECIAL" text only to Excel Sheet
3. Click button
```

They are doing this hundred of times a day and they requested if they can only do step 1 and step 3.

What I needed to do is replicate the Paste Special "TEXT" into that sheet, is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entirely possible. Its just a case of using `.PasteSpecial Format:="Text"`

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: As an addendum to this, if you are feeling adventurous, its possible to have step 1 done by code as well, so its all done with one button. Some examples: http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/ie-automation.shtml http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/using-vba-to-automate-internet-explorer-sessions-from-an-excel-spreadsheet/ http://vbadud.blogspot.co.uk/2009/08/how-to-login-to-website-using-vba.html

Comment: Have made an adjustment to the answer

Comment: Thanks. By the way, this is the code I used. Sheet2.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste = xlPasteValues  .. the problem is it is pasting the images also, how do I format TEXT Only.

Comment: My amended answer should strip out the pictures (using `Format:="Text"` instead). Was working on something for someone else and had xlPasteValues stuck in my head :P