# Cut and Paste Special

Tags: excel

I'm busy trying to create a macro that will copy data from one sheet to another, but the problem is there are values that have been 'conditionally formatted' to be a different font color when certain conditions are met, so when i copy data using a macro I created it does not include the conditions, it just copies the values as they are. Here is my macro code below. Please help.

```
'In this example I am Copying the Data from Sheet1 (Source) to Sheet2 
(Destination)
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
'Method 1
Sheets("FCI").Range("C37:G57").COPY 
Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
'Method 2
'Copy the data
Sheets("FCI").Range("C37:G57").COPY
'Activate the destination worksheet
Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
'Select the target range
Range("A2").Select
'Paste in the target destination
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: So use `.PasteSpecial` and tell it which features you want to paste. If you don't use `PasteSpecial`, you don't get it. And you're not using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Paste Special](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24135703/excel-vba-paste-special)

Comment: or maybe [Copy conditional formatting from one cell to another using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388350/copy-conditional-formatting-from-one-cell-to-another-using-vba)

Comment: Thank you, let me try these